# Nought point five miles. Why is it miles, plural?

Tags: nouns

I read somewhere that 0.5 mile is nought point five miles. Why is 0.5 counted as plural?

Comment: I assume you mean "nought point five"?

Comment: Technically everything about "point five miles" is incorrect. The decimal is correctly read as five-tenths (of a mile) or one-half (mile). You can avoid the issue completely by using the common fraction and simply saying one-half mile, which is what you obviously mean. If you are asking how to say this in writing, that would be the best possible way.

Comment: @ArchieAzares Nothing wrong with "point five". If you are describing something reaching its target, you don't count "nine-tenths of a mile, three-fourths of a mile, seven-thenths...", you'd simply say "point nine miles, point eight miles, point seven...". Context is everything.

Comment: well i think grammatically you are not suppose to use numerals in writing a sentence unless they are over a certain value. Although, cases like this one are usually topics in debate, I'd rather avoid writing numbers which can be express in a better way using fractions.

Comment: There is relatively little "logic" to it.  It's just that, of all the possible awkward conventions, that one is seen as the least awkward by most people, so it's the one that's used.

Answer (score 5):

I believe the simple rule is that every number except 1 is pluralised.  0.5, even though it's less than 1, is not equal to 1, so it's pluralised.

**EDIT**: As **@ruakh** points out in the comments: within this context, "1.0" is not the same as "1", and we *do* say *1.0 miles*.  So, it's only the **integer 1** which is singular.

Comment: never thought like that before.

Comment: +1. Note that we even say "1.0 miles", not \*"1.0 mile": 1.0 and 1 are apparently not the same number as far as English grammar is concerned.

Comment: Excellent point @ruakh, i'll add that to my answer.

Comment: @MaxWilliams I have even heard people say things like *one pounds, fifty-two pence*. I feel sure it was even more common in the days when we had shillings and pence - *one pounds, thirteen and six* but I am not sure we would regard it as best practice, either then or now.

Comment: I think you will always encounter some variation, but in my experience people would either say "one pound fifty-two", "two pound fifty-two" OR "one pound and fifty two pence", "two pounds and fifty two pence", etc.  The first is the short form and is generally never pluralised.

Answer (score -1):

It might be incorrect. But *point five miles* sounds correct to many native English speakers because of the word *five* right before the word *miles*. It's strange to ever say *five mile* regardless of what precedes it which might make it formally correct.

Comment: I'm a native english speaker and "nought point five miles" sounds totally fine to me (although i might be tempted to say "half a mile" if it wasn't in the context of precise measurement).

Comment: But 0.5 mile has 5 before mile too.

Comment: -1, sorry. Note that we also say "zero point one miles", not \*"zero point one mile".